# cannot claim usb interface more than 64 times

Tags: node.js, windows, usb, libusb

I have an app that needs to maintain a long (indefinite) connection to a usb device and print a potentially unlimited number of times to it. So, it needs to make a lot of claims on  the same device interface.

Eventually my app breaks because on the 65th claim I get a `LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS` error thrown. Is it possible to fix this with `node-usb`? Possibly related to

- https://github.com/libusb/libusb/issues/16
- https://github.com/node-usb/node-usb/issues/302#issuecomment-988657538

**environment and hardware**

```
windows 11 home insider preview
nodejs v11.0.0
node-usb v1.5.0
node-escpos v2
```

**code**

```js
function testClaim() {
  const d = new USB();
  const p = new Printer(d, { encoding: 'Shift-JIS' });

  const loop = (curr = 0) => {
    console.log('LOOP', curr)

    if (curr === 50) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        d.open(() => d.reset(() => {
          console.log('RESET', curr)
          // should not require the user to do anything, needs to be able to print indefinitely
          loop(0)
        }))
      }, 1000);
      return;
    }

    d.open(() => {
      p.close(() => {
        loop(curr + 1)
      })
    })
  }

  loop();
}

testClaim();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by using a main thread to manage two child threads

```
MAX_COUNT=6

print 1 [thread]
print 2 [thread]
print 3 [thread, thread] # MAX_COUNT / 2, add the head
print 4 [thread, thread]
print 5 [thread, thread]
print 6 [thread]         # MAX_COUNT, the head becomes the tail, delete the previous tail

always print to the tail thread, it should always exist
this lets you spin up the thread asynchronously
```

Printing inside the forked thread doesn't seem to carry over to other threads so something in `libusb` or `node-usb` seems to be mutating the thread's memory, I'm not sure.